# Solr 5: not loading shards from symlinked directories

Tags: solr, solr5

I've tried to upgrade from Solr 4.10.3 to 5.4.1. Solr shards are placed on different disks and symlinks (ln -s) are created to SOLR_HOME (SOLR_HOME itself is set as an absolute path and works fine).
When Solr starts, it loads only shards placed in home directory, but not symlinked ones.
If I copy shard to home directory (in file system path remains unchanged, like SOLR_HOME/my_shard1, both symlinked and copied), it works.

Are there any ways to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CorePropertiesLocator does NOT follow symlinks it's a known bug, appeared in 5.4, will be fixed in the following release (and there is a ready patch to fix 5.4)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8548